# Can't get Twilio's conversation video preview to show up

Tags: swift, video, twilio

I am trying to use the [sample code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/conversations#render-camera-preview) to get a preview from my camera. However, nothing is happening. I tried many other things, including manually calling `startPreview()` on my `TWCCameraCapturer` property. Interestingly, the preview does show up when I initiate a conversation with a blank recipient.

Comment: It might help if you could share the relevant code you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample is missing a few more lines of code required to get the preview to show. Try this:

```
self.camera!.videoTrack?.attach(self.localMediaView)
self.camera!.videoTrack?.delegate = self;

// Start the preview.
self.camera!.startPreview();
self.localMediaView!.addSubview((self.camera!.previewView)!)
self.camera!.previewView?.frame = self.localMediaView!.bounds
self.camera!.previewView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
self.camera!.previewView?.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```